# What is discrete class variable in Orange?

Tags: orange

I'd like to start trying to train stock price time series using Orange. I have a simple time series for Amazon that is attached to a Logistic Regression widget. The widget throws the error:

> Discrete class variable expected.

Any one know what this means or how to solve it?

Workspace: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e43ssam3higoqgb/stockprice_regression.ows?dl=0

Data file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/38ye3qm92dpbiov/amazon.csv?dl=0

-- EDIT --
Logistics regression has been replaced with linear regression. This moves things along a little.

[image]

Comment: please avoid links to external resources. Include the necessary code and data in your question. If you find it's too much content, reduce to have a http://sscce.org/

Comment: To point of Orange is that there is no code. So there is no code. Also, I'm not going post a time series here. It would run for multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

In order to learn the model in a supervised manner (Logistic regression is the model that need to be learned), you need to tell a model what is the class variable in your data. For Logistic regression which is a classification model, the class variable must be discrete (it represent few classes in data). Since you have a continuous class variable (a class variable is marked as a target in `File` widget) I suggest you use one of the regression models such as `Linear regression` (the model that do not predict classes but values directly).

Comment: I've switched out logistics regression for linear regression and posted an image. Do you understand what the linear regression values are saying? I guess there's not enough other variables for this to really work right? I'm planning to add VIX closing values as well. That should make some difference correct?